# how could I download php page into pdf with css and html?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

[I want to download this page  into pdf after clicking download button.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2qrB.png)

Comment: Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: [html2pdf](https://www.html2pdf.fr/) try this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert HTML + CSS to PDF with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following anchor tag:

```
<a href="/home.php" download="home-downloaded.pdf">Download Home as pdf</a>
```

Comment: How does a php page get converted into a PDF?

Comment: When the page is loaded, all the php codes are converted to html. SO when you click on the link, the html are being saved as a pdf file.